# UINavigationItem image is always centered

Tags: ios, swift

I'm using this code to set custom image in `UINavigationItem`:

```
let button = UIButton(type: .system)
button.frame = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 34, height: 34))
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
button.addTarget(target, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)
leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
```

Effect looks like this:[image: effect]

In comparison screen shot from the same device but from Photos app looks like this:

[image: photos]

As you can see back button in my app is moved a little bit to the center.

Why my image is not the same like in other apps?

Comment: try cropping the image or making it smaller

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set a UIView with your desired width and then add UIButton as subview to that UIView and only then assign to leftbarbuttonItem

```
    let button = UIButton(type: .system)
    button.frame = CGRect(x: -20, y: 0, width: 35, height: 35 )
    button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    button.setImage(UIImage.init(named: "backButton"), for: .normal)

    let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 100, height: 35)));
    view.addSubview(button);
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.yellow

    let leftButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: view)
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftButton
```

Comment: Can you share any code? Because adding this: let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 34, height: 34)));       
 view.addSubview(button);  doesn't work.

Comment: Have you placed image in your tests? Cause it's not working for me.

Comment: Additional view + changing originX did help.

Comment: There is one problem - button click is not working after adding target.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149339/discussion-between-ppinho-and-thirdmartian).